# Vagrant: "Docker installation failed"

Tags: docker, vagrant

I'm using the following Vagrant file:

---

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 27017, host: 27017

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "1024"
  end

  config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
    d.run "mongoDB", image: "mongo:2", args: "-p 27017:27017"
  end

  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-cachier")
    config.cache.scope = :box
  end

end
```

---

Then

```
vagrant up
```

stops with the following error while trying to install Docker:

```
/etc/init.d/vboxadd: 256: /etc/init.d/vboxadd: cannot create : Directory     nonexistent
Unmounting Virtualbox Guest Additions ISO from: /mnt
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
default: /vagrant => D:/Vagrant/<SUBFOLDERNAME>
default: /tmp/vagrant-cache => C:/Users/<ME>/.vagrant.d/cache/ubuntu    /trusty64
==> default: Configuring cache buckets...
==> default: Running provisioner: docker...
default: Installing Docker onto machine...
Docker installation failed.
```

I'm in a corporate network behind a proxy.
Windows 10 notebook, 64 bit.
Vagrant Version: 2.2.1
VirtualBox Version: 5.2.12

Answer (score 1):

For some reason it does't like your ubuntu version.
tried with :
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-20.04"
end
and it's up and running.